# Proguard behavior differs based on build type though setup is relatively identical

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

debug {
    //region Temp
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    //endregion

    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
```

So, I have 2 build types with the same proguard setup. Even though the `debug` build shrinks code, I get runtime errors in the `release` due to, what appears to me, some additional code shrinking. Hence, I can't rely on testing my app and proguard under the `debug` build.

Are there any other flags to specify to reproduce `release`'
s proguard shrinking setup in the `debug` build type?
Also, is there a way to inspect full build type specification (including inherited specs)? Project structure gives some info, however, I believe there's more to it and I also want to checkout buildtype inheritance.

Thanks.

p.s. `compile 'com.github.hosopy:actioncable-client-java:0.1.2'` this dependency does not get shrank in `debug`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `dependencies` part. you might have some dependencies that are not provided in the release build type. like `debugCompile` or `debugImplementation` dependecies that are only available for the debug build type.

Comment: Thanks, but it's just an `implementation` dependency